# SPF Records and Too many DNS lookups

Tags: mx-record, spf

It's been suggested to me that I configure SPF records for my domain and I have done so. I use gsuite for email and have mx records properly configured to send mail via gsuite. My web app sends emails via Sendgrid's API and I also use Mailchimp for marketing emails.

I believe the following is the correct TXT record:

`"v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:sendgrid.com include:servers.mcsv.net ~all"`

However, I have done a few tests which tell me that record includes too many DNS lookups. What's the best course of action here?

Comment: What software/website are you using to reveal DNS issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office365 SPF PermError: Too many DNS lookups](https://serverfault.com/questions/590072/office365-spf-permerror-too-many-dns-lookups)

Comment: Beware of `a` and `mx` in SPF records. They only work reliably if the domains covered by them are dual stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you are using Sendgrid's services, you should [include the record at `sendgrid.net`](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/spf.html) (intended for this purpose), not `sendgrid.com` (appears to reflect what mail services Sendgrid the company themselves use, including things like Google Mail).
Fixing that removes a handful of lookups to other things that are irrelevant to you.

Second, what does `mx` in your SPF record expand to?
As you include `_spf.google.com` in SPF, I would expect that your `MX` records are most likely the Google Mail inbound servers, which are entirely pointless for you to add in SPF (and adds additional lookups).

As for `a`, what is there at that address and does it even send mail? If yes, why not just add the IP address in SPF instead of an indirect reference?

Comment: Hi Håkan, I am thinking now I do not need the a record, the application doesn’t send mail itself (only via the Sendgtif API), is that correct? I’ll remove the mx keyword as well.

Comment: @JaysonLane If the host with the corresponding address only sends mail via Sendgrid, there's no need to allow that host itself.

Answer (score 4):

As you're aware, SPF records are limited to 10 DNS lookups. If they result in more than that, the record fails with a permerror.

---

Here is the problem:

```
include:sendgrid.com
```

This is for Sendgrid's own internal corporate mail. It has its own large set of includes and results in quite a few DNS lookups.

This is *not* what you were supposed to use. Sendgrid customers are supposed to add to their SPF record:

```
include:sendgrid.net
```

Note **net**, not com. This should reduce your DNS lookups below 10 and get you a working (and mostly correct) SPF record.

---

P.S. I say *mostly correct* because your record ends with `~all`, which should be changed to `-all` after you're finished testing the record. The `~all` makes the entire record useless for actually stopping forged mail.