# TXT record for multiple email providers not working

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, txt-record

The main domain is configured with google account so we are using sub-domain: mail.fairwaytoursuae.com for sending mail via Mailgun. Everything is done as in the docs but still, one TXT record is showing the main domain record value.

In mailgun :

[image]

In the server:

[image]

Is there anything wrong in the records? Are they need to combine together?

Comment: Your TXT record is exactly what they specified it should be. Wait four hours and check again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : it's worked after adding CNAME record(TXT records added befor two days)

Comment: @MadHatter : mailgun is not detecting the record added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I see what you're asking, but let me restate your problem, to be clear.  You currently have mail working happily from `fairwaytoursuae.com` via google, and you want to add a new bulk email system using mailgun.  You have been advised to set a new SPF record, and don't quite understand what's going on.

The missing datum is **who** you are sending mailgun mails from; that is, what fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) appears in the host portion of the envelope-From field.  I'm going to assume it's `fairwaytoursuae.com`, *not* `mail.fairwaytoursuae.com`.

The issue here is that mailgun has advised you to advertise an SPF record for `mail.fairwaytoursuae.com`, but their web system shows an SPF record already existing **which is not for that FQDN**.  Instead, their web system is showing you the current SPF record for the **parent** domain, `fairwaytoursuae.com`, even though the interface suggests this is not so.

I suspect what it actually wants is for you to publish a single, combined record for the parent domain.  Something like

```
fairwaytoursuae.com.   IN   TXT   v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:198.57.193.33 include:_spf.google.com include:mailgun.org ~all
```

Even if my guess is right, there are several potential problems with such a record.  One is that you are likely to be getting perilously close to [the limit of ten DNS lookups](https://serverfault.com/q/584708/55514) which represents the maximum the evaluation of an SPF record may require  (another is that it's completely useless, [like all SPF records that don't end `-all`.](https://serverfault.com/a/369478/55514))  SPF isn't really intended for people who have a highly-distributed email infrastructure, and in starting with gmail you've started with one of the biggest on the planet, and are trying to make it bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer... finally it's detected the TXT record after adding cname record for mailgun.

Comment: @PranavCBalan no worries, I'm glad things are working, and thanks for accepting an answer.  Do please consider `-all`; SPF really isn't any use without it.

Comment: Can I use different MX record for main domain and it's sub domain ? For eg : google provider for main.com and mailgun provider for mail.main.com

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes, you may.