# Get list of IPs from an SPF record

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, spf

We do SPF checks on our mail server, I have a incident where mail from MimeCast sometimes passes and then others fails the SPF check.

The domain in question's spf record states

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:_netblocks.mimecast.com -all
```

If I do a whois on the IP it is a Mimecast IP

My question is how can I query `_netblocks.mimecast.com` to get a list of IPs so I can troubleshoot

Comment: I suppose you've ruled out `dig txt _netblocks.mimecast.com` (or just about any other DNS query tool) and following that down?

Comment: dig txt _netblocks.mimecast.com does not give me a list of ip's or at least not on my Centos 6 box

Comment: No, it gives you a list of `include`d records, each of which you can then query with `dig txt foo.bar.com` until you get actual IPs; hence, "*following that down*".

Comment: Got you! thanks that work please add it as a answer so I can mark it

Comment: I'm not sure it justifies one, but I found I had a bigger point to make, so have done so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have discovered that many organisations provide SPF records which are themselves made up of SPF records.  When we do `dig txt _netblocks.mimecast.com` we get

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
_netblocks.mimecast.com. 300    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:eu._netblocks.mimecast.com include:us._netblocks.mimecast.com include:za._netblocks.mimecast.com include:au._netblocks.mimecast.com ~all"
```

Each of those can then be looked up *similarly*, with eg `dig txt eu._netblocks.mimecast.com` to get the raw IP data:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
eu._netblocks.mimecast.com. 300 IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:195.130.217.0/24 ip4:91.220.42.0/24 ip4:146.101.78.0/24 ip4:207.82.80.0/24 ip4:213.167.81.0/24 ip4:213.167.75.0/24 ip4:185.58.84.0/22 ~all"
```

Outlook's record is a bit more annoying (there's a surprise) in that it's nested:

```
[me@risby ~]$ dig txt spf.protection.outlook.com
[...]
spf.protection.outlook.com. 586 IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:207.46.101.128/26 ip4:207.46.100.0/24 ip4:207.46.163.0/24 ip4:65.55.169.0/24 ip4:157.56.110.0/23 ip4:157.55.234.0/24 ip4:213.199.154.0/24 ip4:213.199.180.128/26 include:spfa.protection.outlook.com -all"
```

`spfa` in turn `include`s `spfb`, but that's the last one there, so you can stop digging.

The bigger problem is that this organisation, whoever it is, is getting *perilously* close to the [ten-lookup limit](https://serverfault.com/q/584708/55514).  I count one for the original record, three for the outlook portion, and five for the mimecast portion; total, nine.  If both outlook and mimecast add one more each, this organisation's stuffed.  It may well know this, but I find that most organisations are sublimely unaware of the finer points of their own SPF record.

Which brings me to my bigger point: **if you are thinking of publishing an SPF record, make sure you control your own email infrastructure**.  If you outsource it, someone else may well shoot you in the foot sooner or later, and your corporate email will become undeliverable because of a change you didn't make and don't know about.  If you don't control all your own email, SPF probably isn't for you.